# Creating a custom accessoryView in the UITableViewCell's setSelected and setHighlighted methods is causing the rest of my code to be ignored

Tags: iphone, ios

In my UITableViewCell subclass, I'm overriding the setHighlighted and setSelected methods to change the look of the cell when it's selected, but whenever I set the accessoryView property in either of the methods, all my other code that changes the font and shadow colors is ignored entirely.

For example, using this code will change the text color of the text and detail labels

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    if (selected) {        
        self.textLabel.textColor         = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.textLabel.shadowColor       = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.detailTextLabel.textColor   = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.detailTextLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    } 
}
```

But the moment I add the custom accessoryView to the mix, all the other code is ignored, however the accessoryView image does appear.

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    if (selected) {        
        self.textLabel.textColor         = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.textLabel.shadowColor       = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.detailTextLabel.textColor   = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.detailTextLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        self.accessoryView = 
            [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:styleImage(@"/icons/disclosure_selected.png")];
    } 
}
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong? How can I properly customize the accessoryView and the rest of the cell's code during the selected and highlighted states?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just creating my own UIImageView and hiding the built in one.

Answer (score -2):

I think accessoryView is a UIButton not a UIImageView...
Try this :

```
accessory = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [accessory setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"/icons/disclosure_selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    accessory.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 26, 26);      //You can change it
    accessory.userInteractionEnabled = YES;          //You can change it too
    self.accessoryView = accessory;
```

Hope it'll help

Comment: self.accessoryView is a UIView not a UIButton. You can customize the the accessoryView by creating your own image using UIImageView. Using a UIButton doesn't make sense unless you want the disclosure icon to actually be clickable, but that's not necessary since the tablecell itself is already clickable.